# Two columns of a table referring to PK of another table in JPA

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship

We have two tables

Table1(Name=Comment, PK is "ID"): (Lookup table)

```
ID Description Type
​1  Desc1       Type1
2  Desc2       Type2
```

Table2(Name=Steps, PK is "ID"):(Values has to be persisted and retrieved)

```
ID  Value    Comment1    Comment2
1   Value1    1           2
2   Value2    1           NULL
```

Comment1 and Comment2 are individually referring to ID of table1.

For each step in table 2 there might be different combinations of comment1 and comment2 referring to table1 (Comment1-has values w.r.t table1 with type as Type1, similarly Comment2).

What is the relationship that has to be defined in JPA for the entity comment in entity Step? We tried with ManyToOne on comment1 and comment2 of Step and had the following issues when retrieving the data(Although there was no issue when saving the data),

When retrieving data from Step, the description of comment is not being fetched on certain case where the data was retrieved immediately after persisting. But the value was fetched after the server was restarted. Do we have to explicitly join the tables when fetching(tried left join using criteria query). Should we have to edit the fetch type(tried both eager and lazy). Or does it have to do anything with cache refresh hints?

Annotation currently used,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch =FetchType.Eager, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is not normalized. You should add an intermediate table between comment and steps table.

```
comment table
    ID Description Type
    ​1  Desc1       Type1
    2  Desc2       Type2

step_comment table
    step_id comment_id
    1           1
    1           2
    2           1

step table
    ID  Value    
    1   Value1   
    2   Value2
```

You should consider using many to many association. Below is the example of many to many bidirectional association between 2 entity:

```
@Entity
public class Step {

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name="step_comment",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="step_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
  private List<Comment> comments;
  .....
}

@Entity
public class Comment {

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="comments")
  private List<Step> steps;
  ...
}
```

Please refer to the JPA Wiki for more information: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany